# How can I identify an untranslatable value exists in FormRecognizer analysis

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I posted the following Feature Request to the azure-sdk, but not sure if that was the correct place for getting a response, so reposting here.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/20764

When processing a document against a custom trained model, when a value is present but not able to be translated (such as a signature), would it be possible to include something in the response to identify it as having a value though it wasn't able to be processed?

The specific use case is that our client needs to know that a document was signed by the parties involved. Without this feature, someone will be required to manually review thousands of document images per week to verify that they have been signed.  In testing we have found that very few signatures are being translated any way, so the string response is coming back as null.

Thank you,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

For Form Recognizer when a value is not detected although it is present it will be extracted as Null as Form Recognizer is not aware that a value exists it did not detect it. In case of signature this is usually due to the signature being unreadable and just a scribble.